# Maven surefire java 8 with EasyMock yields: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33

Tags: maven, java-8, easymock, maven-surefire-plugin

I am attempting to upgrade our application to Java 8 and am having some issues with maven and surefire. When I run all of my unit tests, a handful of them fail when using EasyMock.createMock with the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33`. Not all instances of EasyMock.createMock fail, and I can't find anything special about the classes we're mocking where it fails. Also, if I run the unit test inside of IntelliJ it works perfectly fine. It's only when running it via maven directly that it fails. I haven't been able to find anything that is causing this, but I'm assuming it has to be some sort of classpath issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange error. The Proxy33 means you are mocking an interface. And that something failed at class loading.

Check if you have static initializers in your code. You can also add remote debug to maven and break on the exception.